# Ensuring there's only one of every state

Tags: c++

I'm writing a game engine, and right now I was thinking about how I could ensure that ever state in the game (be it an entity state, a game state, etc) has only one instance. Singletons come to mind, but that seems like overkill. One other thing I thought about is nameless classes:

```
class EntityState
{
  public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class : public EntityState
{
  public:
    void foo() {}
} walkLeftState;

// Because it inherits from EntityState, a named class, I can also
// pass it as a parameter:
void Entity::changeState(EntityState* state) {}
```

But the problem is I want to add Python scripting, and I don't think Python has nameless classes. What other options are there?

**Edit:** Why I need only one of every state.

I need a away to identify what state an entity has. I could do it with magic values (i.e. an ID string), but that's a terribly ugly solution, imo. I'd much rather do it by comparing pointers, which I'm ensured to always be unique. But I can't identify by pointers unless there's a single instance of every state...

**Edit 2:** A solution...

I went for function objects in the end. Seeing as the State classes would only contain a function and nothing else, it didn't really make sense having the class in the first place, now that I think about it. In the end, I think I'll go for something like this:

```
typedef void (*EntityStateFunc)(Entity* entity, unsigned long currentTime);

namespace entitystate
{
    void walkLeft(Entity* entity, unsigned long currentTime);
    void stand(Entity* entity, unsigned long currentTime);
}
```

This should pretty much solve everything: no singletons, no complaints that it might make testing harder, it's simple... Only possible disadvantage is that I'll pretty much have my hands tied if a state ever needs to be more than a function; can anyone think of a scenario where a state needs to be something more complex than this?

Comment: Is it really that important to ensure?

Comment: How often do you accidentally create an object that you don't really need?

Comment: @jalf It would be nice. It's not necessary and if I can't find a reasonable solution, I'll just give up on the idea.

Comment: @FredOverflow Thoughts like that, I try to avoid when programming something. If I do it right the first time, then when I use it down the road I don't have to worry about using it the wrong way, because the only way I could possibly use it is the right one.

Comment: @Paul: but you should also try to avoid thoughts like "I'll do a ton of extra work *now*, in order to *maybe* save some trouble later down the road. Anyway, more significantly, "one instance" means "impossible to test". Allowing yourself to create more instances means they can be created ad-hoc for testing purposes. As @Fred says, accidentally creating objects isn't really the #1 most common problem. Why go to the trouble of adding complexity, and reducing testability just to prevent it? Make it uncopyable, to eliminate a common error source, but not inconstructible.

Comment: @Paul: I could also add that *no one* ever "does it right the first time". It's a waste of time to try to shoot for that, because you won't succeed. Instead, aim to do as little as possible *wrong* the first time. That includes not building in constraints that you're not 100% sure of

Comment: @Paul: yes, that means that only one instance should be used in the game. It does *not* mean that it should be impossible to create more than one instance. Like I said, testing becomes much easier if you allow yourself to create another instance *when needed*. And for the game itself, just create one instance and use that throughout

Comment: re: singletons and the "need" for one and just one instance: [read this](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)

Comment: @jalf States have only function membranous. Multiple instances would not help testing.

Comment: @Paul: yes they would, simply by minimizing the mental overhead. If each test creates its environment from scratch, then you don't even have to think about "could it have been using polluted data left over from the previous test?" That's a huge advantage. Even if the answer was "no, it was safe to reuse that object", the fact that you have to think about it, and ask the question slows you down.

Comment: @jalf One instance doesn't mean impossible to test---I regularly test applications with just one instance.  In this particular case, one instance does mean that you can't have states which differ only in data; that's occasionally useful in the state pattern.  More importantly, of course, the derived class (the one of which there should only be a single instance) is not visible outside the source file, so the chances of misuse are significantly less, and it's probably not worth the bother of defending against them.

Comment: @jalf With regards to tests: the state objects in the state pattern are immutable, so there's no problem about polluted data.  But a good test harness will run each test in a separate process, just to be sure.

Comment: @James: Who says that State objects are per se immutable?

Answer (score 4):

Just create one of every state.

There is no reason to make your code so complicated by attempting to enforce this.

Do you write a function like this:

```
int foo() {
   int x = 5;
   x++;

   return x;
}
```

And then go, oh my god, I only need one integer variable inside this function... *I must enforce this*? No.

Comment: Have you written any code elsewhere that relies for correctness on the fact that `foo` only uses one variable? No. So the situation is not analagous to the questioner's situation.

Comment: @Steve: If code _anywhere_ relies on there only being only one instance of a datatype, then your encapsulation is broken, your object abstraction is broken, your use of OOP as a whole is broken, and your code is broken.

Comment: @Steve: Really? I do it all the time: `int result = 0; /* ... complicated logic ... */ return result;` How do I ensure that I don't accidentally create and return a different variable? :)

Comment: @Tomalak: But you did read the question, right? So you know that despite being contrary to your style guide, that's what's happening in the questioner's case.

Comment: @Steve: No, the OP _thinks_ it pertains. The entire point of my answer is that it, actually, _absolutely does not_. Or, at the very least, if it does, then **that** is the problem that should be solved.

Comment: Nevertheless, your attempted analogy is useless, since it doesn't address the questioner's mistakes.

Comment: @Steve: I'm sorry that you can't see the connection.

Comment: Usually I appreciate sarcastic hyperbole, I just don't think that in this case it will enlighten the questioner. The fact that your straw man is absurd, because you never want to rely on a function using only one variable, *has no relevance* to whether you (perhaps foolishly) want to rely on a type having one instance.

Comment: @Steve: No sarcasm, and no hyperbole. And I think that "there is no reason to make your code so complicated by attempting to enforce this" is perfectly clear, and perfectly enlightening.

Comment: @Tomalak: if I thought that part of your answer was wrong too, I'd have said so ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid creating a hard constraint, and instead ensure that you're notified if and when you ever create more than you expected:

```
template <typename T>
struct expected_unique {
    static int &getcount() {
        static int count = 0;
        return count;
    }
    static void object_created() {
        int &lcount = getcount();
        ++lcount;
        if (lcount > 1) {
            std::err << "More than one " << typeid(T).name() << " " << lcount << "\n";
        }
    }
    expected_unique() {
        object_created();
    }
    expected_unique(const expected_unique&) {
        object_created();
    }
    // optionally, if you only want to check no more than one at a time 
    // rather than no more than one ever.
    ~expected_unique() {
        --getcount();
    }
};

class WalkLeftState : public EntityState, private expected_unique<WalkLeftState> {
};
```

Obviously it's not thread-safe, you could make it so with a lock or with atomic `int` operations.

If there really is only one function, another alternative is:

```
class EntityState
{
  void (*foo_func)();
  public:
    EntityState(void(*f)()) : foo_func(f) {}
    bool operator==(const EntityState &rhs) {
        return foo_func == rhs.foo_func;
    }
    bool operator!=(const EntityState &rhs) {
        return !(*this == rhs);
    }
    void foo() { foo_func(); }
};

void walk_left_foo() {
}

EntityState walkLeftState(walk_left_foo);
```

Now, it doesn't matter whether or not there are multiple instances of `EntityState` using the same function, because comparison is performed according to whether the two states involved execute the same routine. So just switch your existing pointer comparisons to object comparisons.

However, if there's more than one virtual function in `EntityState` in real life, then this would be pretty unwieldy.

Comment: Could you please take a look at Edit 2?

Comment: @Paul: "can anyone think of a scenario where a state needs to be something more complex than this". Since I don't know anything really about your game, I can think of a lot of things. You said somewhere that you don't want to put representation data into your state, but I don't necessarily see why you shouldn't ever want to put *any* data into your state. In any case, you don't achieve a useful encapsulation by having lots of different bits of code, all over the place, that need to special-case every state, so it might not be such a bad idea to have representation (or other) data in the state.

Answer (score 2):

Singletons probably are overkill here.  It's laudable to be defensive in
your programming, and to prevent misuse, but in this case, the simplest
solution is just to define each of the state classes in an unnamed
namespace in the source file.  You not going to create multiple
instances in this one file, and no one else can even name them, much
less define an instance of one.  (You can also leave them unnamed, but
that means no user defined destructor.)

Comment: Could you please take a look at Edit 2?

Answer (score 0):

> I need a away to identify what state an entity has.

Why? To be able to switch on the state? That's exactly what the State pattern should prevent you from doing in the first place. It replaces "switching on states" with polymorphism. That is, instead of this:

```
switch (state.getState())
{
    case WALK_LEFT:
        --x;
        break;

    case WALK_RIGHT:
        ++x;
        break;

    case WALK_UP:
        --y;
        break;

    case WALK_DOWN:
        ++y;
        break;
}
```

you just say:

```
state.step();
```

and let the concrete `step` member functions do the right thing.

Comment: Because the representation needs to know what state its entity is in. Based on the state, it plays a different animation. I don't want to include representation data in the state...

Comment: @Paul: Then you should look into the Visitor pattern.

Comment: Is it the same as Observer Pattern? It doesn't really address my problem. Anyway, could you please take a look at Edit 2?

Comment: Erm, no? [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) vs. [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

As I "hinted at" in the comments, enforcing a "only one instance may exist" constraint is nearly always the wrong thing to do. Actually, I'm willing to go out on a limb and say that it *is* always the wrong thing to do.

Instead, make it impossible to **accidentally** create new instances, but allow the programmer (you) to do so *when you really want to*.

In C++, there are two common ways in which instances might "accidentally" get created:

```
EntityState st = otherState;

EntityState st2;
```

Copy constructors are probably the #1 offender. It's easy to forget the `&`, so suddenly instead of creating a reference to the object, you create a copy. So prevent this by making the class noncopyable.

The default constructor is a less serious issue, but you might, for example, create a class member of type `EntityState`, and forget to initialize it. And voilá, the default constructor gives you a new instance of the class.

So prevent that too. Declare a constructor taking one or more parameters (which you don't *accidentally* call), ensure that no default constructor exists, and that the copy constructor is private.

Then you have to consciously think about it and *want* to create an instance before it happens. And so, as long as the programmer is sane, you'll only have one instance whenever you *want* just one instance to exist.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Defensive programming is never wrong.  In this particular case, it's probably overkill, but it's certainly not wrong.  The state pattern requires exactly one instance of each state, no more no less, and if the individual state types were part of the interface, and could be accessed by client code, *not* protecting against multiple instances would be a case of sloppy programming.

Comment: @James: You contradict yourself. If it is "never wrong", then it can never be overkill either. And yes, it is wrong if you defend against something you may need to do later. And you know what's **definitely** wrong? Allowing patterns to dictate what your code does. If the state patterns requires exactly one instance of each state, then the state pattern is wrong, because you might just need two instances of one state somewhere, at some point that you didn't anticipate. And if you read my answer, I offer a perfectly good way to protect against sloppy programming

Comment: I make it impossible to *accidentally* instantiate the class, avoiding the "sloppy programming" problem. But at the same time, I don't "defend" against something I'm not sure I want to defend against.

Comment: @jalf The state pattern definitely requires one, and only one instance per state.  If you don't know whether you want to prevent it or not, you don't know the pattern you're trying to implement, which is serious.

Comment: @James: no, you've still got it upside down. The state pattern is something you use **if you need exactly what it describes**. If you need something else, or if your requirements for now and all future are not 100% set in stone, then you may not yet know whether the state pattern is at all relevant to you. Which is not serious, but extremely common. The pattern is a tool, to be used or discarded at convenience. It is not something that *chooses* to be used, and which then forces you to change your code to fit it.

Comment: Another thing you're forgetting is that the state pattern describes a system in which one instance of each state exists. But it says nothing about how many states might be called for *outside* of that system. It says nothing about whether two systems running in parallel should use the same state instances, or whether my test cases should reuse the same instance, or create their own

Comment: But the moment you put the pattern *first*, and design your code to fit the pattern, you've already lost.

Comment: @jalf The moment you start letting foolish prejudices influence your design, you've lost already.  In this case, the design requires one and only one instance of each state.  Ensuring that programmatically is good defensive programming (albeit overkill in this case).  Reject the singleton idiom because of some foolish prejudice, when it is an appropriate solution, and you've already lost.